# Facing an error in MVC DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new here on STACKOVERFLOW...

I'm just facing an error during adding a Student in the selected DDL item..

**Model 1:** ***Department***

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int deptid { get; set; }
    public string deptname { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Model 2: *Student***

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int stdid { get; set; }
    public string stdname { get; set; }
    public string stdaddress { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int deptid { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**DepartmentsController:**

```
public class DepartmentsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Departments
    public ActionResult AddDepartment()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddDepartment(Department model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
            {
                db.Departments.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**StudentsController:**

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Students
    public ActionResult AddStudent()
    {
        DbAccess db = new DbAccess();
            SelectList datalist = new SelectList(db.Departments.ToList(), "deptid", "deptname");
            ViewBag.deptid = datalist;
            return View();


    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddStudent(Student model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DbAccess db = new DbAccess())
            {
                db.Students.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Students View:**

```
@model MVC_Practice2.Models.Student

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddStudent";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
SelectList datalist = ViewBag.deptid;
}
.
.
.

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deptid, "deptid", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">              
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.deptid,datalist)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.deptid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when I add a student in the selected department from DDL I faced the below error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'deptid' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

And the below line highlighted:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.deptid, datalist)
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIg0U.jpg)

Comment: SelectList datalist = ViewBag.deptid; Notice: you are storing deptid in datalist

Comment: sorry don't understand.... where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Read the duplicate! You do not repopulate the `SelectList` in the POST method so when you `return View(model)` its `null` and the exception is thrown

Comment: Refill value in [HttpPost] AddStudent ActionMethod in ViewBag.deptid

Comment: code Snippet

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddStudent(Student model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DbAccess db = new DbAccess())
                {
                    db.Students.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    SelectList datalist = new SelectList(db.Departments.ToList(), "deptid", "deptname");
                    ViewBag.deptid = datalist;
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: You should use Department.DeptId in your dropdown.
1 - Load list of departments in your action with name DepartmentList
2 - bind your dropdown as :

   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Student.Department.DeptId, new SelectList(Model.Student.DepartmentList, "Deptid ", "Deptname", Model.Student.Department), " - Select - ", new { @class = "form-control pull-left" })

Comment: bundle of thanks to you @Saineshwar your code just works pretty good ... please put it as an answer ... but I have a shopping cart project I did the same thing but it doesn't give me an error can you please llil bit explain it and thnx you have saved my day